# Doing arithmetic on every line in a single file?

Tags: python, bash

I have a file with a lot of rows and they all numbers, and i want to add them and get the total of them all, then i'll put it in a loop so it will do this math all the time supplying the result number of all these rows,, i couldn't do this in bash. 
This example say i'll run this on 100 different servers and i want to add each line in this somefile to the second one and on, on .

Ex:

```
netstat -ant | grep -c :80 > /path/to/somefile
```

Is there a way for this in bash or Python ?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what your input file looks like? Do you only want to sum the (single column?) row values in each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk:

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script

```
sum=0;
while read p; do
  sum=$(($sum + $p));
done <yourfile.txt

echo $sum
```

Comment: Or just `(( sum += p ))`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, string operations are easy. However, a little info is needed.

- What are the types of the numbers? (int, float, etc)
- What are separating the numbers? (commas, tabs, spaces)

The general form is something like:

```
while (1)
sum = 0
with open /path/to/somefile as f:
 for line in f:
  sum_list = (line.split('number_separator')
   for entry in sum_list:
    sum += number_type(entry)
```

Now, sum will be the sum of the file. What you choose to do with it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for this ,, it's all int like :
123123
12312
45645

Comment: So your separator is ' ' (space character) and your number types are int. Just  stick that in the code above I gave you and it should work! You will want to avoid the while (1) loop though, and supply a list of files instead